# Cordova run in browser giving Error: listen EACCES. Is this a nodejs issue?

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I recently installed cordova using npm and I'm having an issue when running a test application. I installed cordova using `npm install -g cordova` and created the project using `cordova create hello`. I added browser platform using `cordova platform add browser`, then used `cordova build` to build the project.

When I attempt to run in a browser using `cordova run browser` I get the following error:

```
c:\Users\{user}\Documents\Cordova\hello>cordova run browser
Running command: cmd "/s /c "c:\Users\{user}\Documents\Cordova\hello\platforms\browser\cordov
a\run.bat""
c:\Users\{user}\Documents\Cordova\hello\platforms\browser\cordova\node_modules\cordova-serve\
node_modules\q\q.js:155
            throw e;
            ^

Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:8000
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:897:20)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1221:19)
at listen (net.js:1270:10)
at Server.listen (net.js:1366:5)
at module.exports (c:\Users\{user}\Documents\Cordova\hello\platforms\browser\cordova\node
_modules\cordova-serve\src\server.js:134:8)
at c:\Users\{user}\Documents\Cordova\hello\platforms\browser\cordova\node_modules\cordova
-serve\src\platform.js:45:16
at _fulfilled (c:\Users\{user}\Documents\Cordova\hello\platforms\browser\cordova\node_mod
ules\cordova-serve\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (c:\Users\{user}\Documents\Cordova\hello\platforms\browser\c
ordova\node_modules\cordova-serve\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (c:\Users\{user}\Documents\Cordova\hello\platforms\bro
wser\cordova\node_modules\cordova-serve\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

Is this an issue with Cordova or is this a node.js issue? Is something wrong with ports or firewall maybe? I'm on a work network using a work laptop, is it possible that this is causing issues?

Comment: I found a solution to the problem. Apparently there was some process that was listening on port 8000 so to solve this you can do one of two things. There is a file named `run` in the directory `platforms\browser\cordova` that has port 8000 hardcoded on like 39. Change that or run cordova with this command: `cordova run --target=chrome --port=5000`. Hope this helps someone else!